# Using pickle to save a list

Tags: python, git, flask

I'm working on some code that takes a list of data, stores it in a file, and then pushes it to git.  The app is server based however and storing the files locally isn't ideal.  Here is what I have for dumping to a file:

```
def store_list_data(data_list, parsed_list_id):
    with open(('list.info.' + str(list_id) + '.txt'), 'wb') as f:
    return pickle.dump(data_list, f)
```

Is it possible that I could just store the files data in a variable (It's a very small file) and then push that to git directly without having actually persistently stored files on the server.

Comment: How do you plan to clone/pull this file later?

Comment: Be aware that unpickling a pickle can cause arbitrary code execution. It's a lot easier to catch malicious code in a bad commit than it is to catch a malicious pickle.

Comment: Pickling to a bytestring instead of a file is super easy. Just `pickle.dumps`. The trickier part is going to be pushing it to a remote git repository.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm still researching the git side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is a *file* content manager, so storing a content to a *file*, to be added to the index, be committed and then pushed is mandatory.

You would need instead to stream the pickle.dump content to another server (one where a Git repo is, and where some job could detect the new file, and add it to said Git repo).
From that other server, you could push to the target remote repo.

Comment: I'd say it's more of a *commit* manager, but commits contain files, so the first paragraph point that you do have to write the data to a file stands.

Comment: @torek "commit manager"? Interesting. I only saw "information manager" (from hell) in the first Git commit https://github.com/git/git/commit/e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290, in which Linus refers to a "stupid (but extremely fast) directory content manager" and "idiotic file manager" (he must have been in a good mood that day)